# JQuery draggable image with saved position

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-ui, draggable

OK it's getting awkward, already searched and tried for about 5 hours and I'm just running in circles...

The scenario is easy: It's the header image of a user profile, it can be dragged into an position and then the top position of the image get's saved into a DB.

Thanks to Beetroot-Beetroot's "containment: 'parent'" I am down to this piece of code, which actually reacts as I want it to! Except for one big problem. The Picture just jumps either to the top or the bottom. There is no smooth scrolling? If I change the 'parent' to -'parent' it scrolls nicely but... the containment of course isn't there anymore. Help? :D

The JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".headerimage").css('cursor','s-resize');
    $(".headerimage").draggable({ containment: 'parent', scroll: false, axis: "y",    stop: function(event, ui) {
            var data = "profileheaderposition="+ui.position.top;
            var destination = "/modules/users/profile/save.php";
            get_data(data, destination, function(test){
                notice(test);
            });
        }
    });                 
});
```

So and last but not least the Header is included like that:

```
<div class="<?php if ($user->id == $profileuser->id) echo "changer"; ?> ui-corner-all" id="profileheader" style="overflow: hidden; width: 650px; height: 260px; position:relative;">
<?php if($profile->profileheader){
    $size = getimagesize($profile->profileheader);
?>
<img id="" class="draggable headerimage" style="position: absolute; top: <?php echo $profile->profileheaderposition; ?>px;" src="<?php echo $profile->profileheader; ?>" alt="profileheader" width="650" />
```

As I said hours of googling weren't giving any results - and if i wouldn't save the results it would work just fine but oh well...

-- Edit --

Right now I am about to cry out -.- I've set up a bounty on this one and the tools for helping me ain jsfiddle but an guest account on my webpage which is:
http://www.animize.de

There you can log on to the page with the Username: Gast and the pw gast - Click on the top right on the name (gast) and you'll see the profile - there you can move the headerpicture - and of course it should behave in another way than it does - help :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UAgDA/25/ here is an fiddle with some running code which explains the behaviour!

Comment: sorry to ask this.. what is wrong with your version with parent: 'parent' ? I can see scrolling image smoothly.. what is it failing?

Comment: with 'parent' it either "jumps" to the bottom or top of the image (at least in chrome)  if I want to scroll it - or / if i make the parent value negative by adding a "-" it works as expected - just that it hast no containment anymore - meaning: i can scroll the image even out of the screen :(

Comment: sorry can't understand, your image is already bigger than the rectangle where you show it, so whenever you move (=scroll) the image it will be out of screen (meaning out of the bounds of the rectangle)..

Comment: The goal is to have a system like facebook on their timeline or google+ at their profiles to clear some missunderstandings

Comment: I don't have facebook timeline nor a google+ profile, but I searched, it's something similar to this what you want ? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGxdTfYIzC8#t=01m20s   But you want to do it similar by just dragging the image inside the rectangle and taking care the image does not leaves blank space in the rectangle when dragging it too far.. isn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UAgDA/35/).

I added an if-statement to the `drag` event which checks the current positioning of the image and sets the current top position into `ui.position.top` if the condition returns true so the draggable event does not increase or decrease the top position while hitting the boundaries of the div. This way you can keep the position properties of your div's.

Comment: Works just fine and the way I wanted - thanks for all the fish

Answer (score 3):

Ivan,

It's hard to see why the code should be in a named function wrapper. Unless dragability needs to be turned on/off, then `.draggable()` just needs to be invoked once in a `$(function(){...});` structure.

It's also hard to see why you would need to write static data from php into javascript. There should be nothing about the draggable image that javascript/jQuery cannot discover for itself by enquiring the DOM, and even then it's not clear why this might be necessary.

I would expect to see something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $(".headerimage").draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        scroll: false,
        axis: "y",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $.ajax(
                url: "/modules/users/profile/save.php",
                data: "profileheaderposition=" + ui.position.top,
                success: function() {
                    //do something here to indicate that the new position has been successfully saved
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That  containment: 'parent', seems to be working like a charm! Thanks for that, however it has now a funny behavior, while dragging it jumps either to the top of the picture or the bottom? (No smooth scrolling)?

Comment: Ivan, see if you can set up a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** with the same symptoms, then post a link to it here.

Answer (score 3):

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkV7Y/16/) for my solution to this. I also handled left and right dragging, which is not necessary for your case at this time but could be useful in future if you plan to use an image greater than its parent. In your case your image is same width as its parent so I added a `threshold` param to let vertical dragging be used without being canceled by the right and left boundaries being hit.

I also added some css for `grab` and `grabbing` cursors, so to get a cursor effect similar to when you drag a pdf around, unfortunately the support for this cursors is somewhat broken in some browsers(IE and chrome in my tests) but firefox is showing them right.

Pasting my code here to prevent from a future fiddle broken link.

HTML:

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="ui-widget-content" style="padding:10px;">

<div class="picturecontainer" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 650px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid #888;">
    <img style="position: absolute;" class="headerimage ui-corner-all" src="http://www.animize.de/modules/users/profile/images/profileheader/header_3722386791348526090.jpg" />
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerimage {
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
}
.grabbing {
  cursor:grabbing !important;
  cursor:-moz-grabbing !important;
  cursor:-webkit-grabbing !important;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var container = $(".picturecontainer");
var childimage = $(".headerimage");

childimage.draggable({  scroll: false, start:function(event,ui) {
                  childimage.addClass('grabbing');
     }, stop: function(event, ui) {
                  childimage.removeClass('grabbing');
     },drag: function(event,ui) {
        //left and right threshold
        //to ease draggin images that have same width as container
        threshold = 20;//pixels
        ltop = childimage.offset().top -1 > container.offset().top;
        lbottom = childimage.offset().top + childimage[0].offsetHeight 
                  <= container.offset().top + container[0].offsetHeight;
        lleft = childimage.offset().left > container.offset().left + threshold;
        lright = childimage.offset().left + childimage[0].offsetWidth <
                container.offset().left + container[0].offsetWidth - threshold;
        if (ltop || lbottom || lleft || lright) {
            $(this).data("draggable").cancel();
            if (ltop) {
                 $(this).offset({ top: $(this).parent().offset().top+1});
            } else if (lbottom) {
                newtop = container.offset().top + container[0].offsetHeight 
                         - childimage[0].offsetHeight;
                $(this).offset({ top: newtop+1});
            } else if (lleft) {
                newleft = container.offset().left;
                $(this).offset({ left: newleft});
            } else if (lright) {                     
                newleft = container.offset().left + container[0].offsetWidth;
                          - childimage[0].offsetWidth;
                $(this).offset({ left: newleft});
            }
         }
     }
}).parent().bind('mouseout',function() {
     childimage.trigger('mouseup');
});
```

Comment: It's a nice bit of code, allthough I prefer QQpings solution as it's nice and and slick. Even then still thanks for trying to help :).

Answer (score 2):

I am using this code in my project and it is working fine. I used the solution from QQping and i just did a small change to make the image to move left and right as well. I hope it helps..

http://jsfiddle.net/UAgDA/266/

```
//Moving left and right
if(ui.position.left >= 0)
{
    ui.position.left = 0;
}                                     
else if(ui.position.left <= x1 - x2)
{    
    ui.position.left = x1 - x2;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: This is not a complete answer. It doesn't address saving the position at all. It barely covers limiting the movement to a certain area, but not how to start or end the moving.

Comment: Bootstrap is overwriting this code, due to which only scroll is only happenign from (Top to bottom) and (bottom to Top), not left, right. Can someone help please!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need to contain it inside `parent` or else you wont be able to drag it upwards outside the `parent` boundary

Alternatively , jQuery ui provides [containment](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) inside two coordinates.

Try this code,

**HTML**

```
<div class="picturecontainer" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 650px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid #888;">
    <img class="headerimage" src="http://www.animize.de/modules/users/profile/images/profileheader/header_3722386791348526090.jpg" />  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var img = $(".headerimage");
    img.css('cursor', 's-resize');
    var x1 = img.parent().width() - img.width();
    var y1 = img.parent().height() - img.height();
    $(".headerimage").draggable({
        containment: [x1,y1,0,0],
        scroll: false,
        axis: "y",
        stop: function(event, ui) {

        }
    });
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/Zf2vk/1/)

Comment: Actually I had almost the same code before - and it doesn't work. It's the same behaviour as I had. Now ich can move the Picture over the bottom border so that there is a white space left - and I can't move it down as far as I should. It's probably something about the positioning of the divs but they can't be changed! http://www.animize.de/users/profile/1 this is the page we are talking about btw.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get your comment. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf2vk/8/ the behaviour is almost like here (of course without the -150) - as I said i guess it's about the positioning of the divs but i just can't seem to guess how to avoid it.

Comment: So, you want to move the picture down and keep the whitespace at top of image . Right ?

Comment: Sry it's early in the morning, I guess my english is some kind of rusty right now... I want it to behave like in your demo - but it behaves as in the demo i added. (yes copied your demo, tried it out didn't work in the design i am using - and because of that i think it something about the absolute and relative positioning of the design instead of just beeing jsproblem but on the other hand i can't understand why it should be as the img is in the container so it should just behave the way it does in your demo - as i said i am kind of getting angry with this feature...)

Comment: I am not getting whats wrong in mine (or yours ) jsfiddle demo. I think you are trying to say thatit is working fine in jsfiddle but not on my website. But the cover pic in you website is not draggable.(There's some js error in your code.) So, I am not able to see whats the problem in your website. Also, can you reproduce the same in jsfiddle ?

Comment: K I just set up an guest account where you can log on and change it: Username: Gast // pw: gast - there you click on the upper right on the name (gast) than you see the profile -> there you can directly move the header...

Comment: sorry, but I couldnt find a place from where I can log in. It just asks to register.

Comment: Actually it's on the upper part of the screen "Benutzername" is Username and the **** is the password

Comment: I would suggest to remove `position:absolute` or any other style from your image (`.headerimage`)

Comment: Even if I do so, it doesn't change a thing - as I have to keep the top / margin-top (without position absolute) to indicate where the starting position of the image is (the one that's saved by the dragging!)